# Android CookieManager Set secure attribute of cookie

Tags: android, cookies, webview

Referring this

[How to secure a cookie in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270273/how-to-secure-a-cookie-in-android)

I want to use cookie with the webview in my android application. I want to set secure attribute of the cookie.  Means cookie will only be sent with requests made over an encrypted connection(HTTPS). Please help...

```
WebView webview = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
setContentView(webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webview.getContext());
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
cookieManager.setCookie(url,value);
cookieSyncManager.sync();

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}

});
webview.loadUrl(url)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set cookie attributes like this

> CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url,"JSESSIONID=1ADF23ADS;
>    secure ");.